# Google Apps Script returns Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to `POST` a request to a simple app script. 
Here's the code:

```js
var BACKEND_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyYAWMv6O8Xld1EvqPuBk9EgxgfpVNly3dyX3JkSc3h/dev";
data = {"obj1": "data1", "obj2": "data2"};
function doGet() {
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(BACKEND_URL, {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  });
  Logger.log(resp);
}
```

And here's the code for the server which should accept POST requests:

```js
function doGet() {
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("posted");
  return;
}
```

NOTE: there's no user part in the URL, so this question isn't the same as a similar one posted in SO.

As a response a get an html page where it's said that sorry, Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again.

I've re-checked the page and it does exist.

Comment: not sure what the /dev trailing the URL does exactly (I am by no means well-versed in Google API), but what happens if you omit it or change it to /edit? I have a vague recollection of running into a similar problem that had to do with sandboxing, i.e. the /dev url not being a 'live' url.

Comment: It's same either you use exit or dev. Dev is used for development, exec for production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the project with `doGet()` including `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is the different from the project with  `doPost(e)`. And you want to call `doPost()` by running `doGet()` including `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. If my understanding your situation is correct, can you confirm the following points.

- `BACKEND_URL` you are using includes `dev`. This is used for using the latest code. But there is a limitation as follows. So please try to use **Current web app URL** like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec`.

  The second is the link labeled latest code and ends in /dev. This URL can only be accessed by users who have edit access to the script. This instance of the app always runs the most recently saved code — not necessarily a formal version — and is intended for quick testing during development.
- At Web Apps, when there are no return messages, the error message of `The script completed but did not return anything.` is returned. If you want to get the return message, please set it using [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content).
- When the script at Web Apps side was modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as a new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.

#### References :

- [Deploying a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)
- [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)

### Edit :

When you deploy Web Apps, please try the following settings.

- "Me" for "Execute the app as:"
- "Anyone, even anonymous" for "Who has access to the app:"

Comment: I've used the exec too, there's no difference.

Comment: Also, I am not sure you need to redeploy the app with a new version every time there's a change. IMO, you could just update using the same version.

Comment: It doesn't help, unfortunately :( Thanks for help anyways!

Comment: @elena I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice that you had already tried exec. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? And about the redeploy of Web Apps, in your case, when you modify ``doPost(e)``, please redeploy it as a new version. By the way, was my understanding for your situation correct?

Comment: @elena Although I'm not sure whether this becomes a reference for your situation, I confirmed that in my environment, when the endpoint including ``dev`` is used, the error of ``Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.`` occurs. But when the endpoint including ``exec`` is used, the error of ``The script completed but did not return anything.`` occurs because of no return values. When ``return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok')`` is used for ``doPost(e)``, no error occurs.

Comment: @elena If this was not your solution, please tell me. I would like to think of other solutions.

Comment: In my own code I actually use the "exec" version, not the "dev". No idea why I posted it. Also I've tried publishing the apps with the new version. It doesn't help :(

Comment: @elena I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. By the way, was my understanding for your situation in my answer correct? And can I ask you about your settings for the deployed Web Apps?

Comment: Actually, you know what, I've tried now what you've suggested: the allow anyone, even anonymous, and it did return "OK". So it guess it could be because of that? I will test more and accept if it all works :) THANKS!

Comment: @elena Thank you for replying about it. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I think that your settings for Web Apps is correct, and also your script of client side is correct. In my environment, I could confirm that your setting and script works fine, again. I would like to also think of about other reasons.